# Purrr package not installing in R 3.4.4

Tags: r, tidyr, ubuntu-18.04, purrr

I tried to install purrr package in R 3.4.4 using install.packages(). But its not able to install and shows an error related to *pluck*

Methods I tried

- install.packages("purrr")
- install.packages("purrr", dependencies = T)
- install.packages("purrr",repos = NULL, dependencies = T)
- install.packages("purrr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
- install.packages("purrr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org", dependencies = T)

The error I get is shared in the image below. Can anyone shed some light on how to go about this issue?

[image]

Comment: your r version is nearly 5 years old. Can you update?

Comment: ... or you _may_ be able to install binary versions for your ubuntu release: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/olderreleasesREADME.html

Comment: This seems (almost) reason-enough for the tidyr-maintainers to increase the minimum R version above R-3.4.4. Though it could also be due to a version of `tcc` or something closely related. Really, though, I suggest you strongly consider upgrading your R to something more recent than > 4.5 years old.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I need to use R 3.4.4 for a specific purpose. I was able to fix this by installing an older version of the purrr package:

#download purrr version 0.3.3 from:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/purrr/

```
#Running R 3.4.4
install.packages("/....../purrr_0.3.3.tar.gz",  # path to downloaded file
                  repos = NULL,
                  type = c("source"),
                  INSTALL_opts = "--no-test-load",
                  lib = "/...") # where to install
```